# What's the difference in 'rollable' and 'normal' basecoat?

Tags: painting, plaster, primer

We got our interior walls and ceilings plastered. Before painting the walls, we've been advised to use a primer / base coat (*"voorstrijk"* in Dutch)  to seal the walls and reduce the absorption of paint into the fresh gypsum.

There seem to be two varieties of *voorstrijk*: one that can be applied with rollers (more expensive), and one that can be applied with a brush (cheaper). I think using a roller is easier, but I'm not sure if it's worth the price difference.

What's the difference between these varieties? What makes the 'normal' variety unsuitable for application with a roller? Or conversely, can I just use the 'normal' variety with a roller?

Comment: Don't know about the differences you're asking about, so this is just a comment: If you put value on your time, the rollable may end up being cheaper than the brushable because it takes less time to apply. It may also give you a better looking (smoother) finish to apply your top coat over.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm certainly leaning towards using a roller, but I am wondering why a product would be incompatible with rollers at all - perhaps the real question I want to ask is 'Can I just apply the normal variety with a roller'?

Comment: _that_ sounds like a better question, but it's more general as written.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with a "roller" vs "brush" primer. The only thing I can assume here is that is that they're describing "new drywall" ([example](https://www.kilz.com/primer/kilz-drywall-pva)) vs normal primer ([example](https://www.kilz.com/primer/kilz-2)), where the former is thinner and cheaper.

New drywall is porous and tends to absorb more paint as a result. New drywall primer is a thinner primer designed to fill those gaps and nothing else (i.e. it won't block stains, etc). I've used it with rollers and never had a problem.

Comment: I was actually thrown off by two products sold at the local DIY stores here: [rollable](https://www.hornbach.nl/shop/ALABASTINE-Rolbare-voorstrijk-zuiging-en-hechting-5-l/7226757/artikel.html) and [normal](https://www.hornbach.nl/shop/ALABASTINE-Sneldrogende-voorstrijk-5-l/8423163/artikel.html). Both don't block stains (they are, in fact, transparent), so I'm guessing that they made a slightly more viscous version for easier rolling (less dripping) and better marketing purposes.  But if you say that thinner primer can be applied just as well with a roller, I'm happy to take that as an answer!

Comment: Washed both through Google translate and it's still not any clearer what the difference is. The roller one mentions "adhesion", so I assume it's thicker or stickier so the roller "rolls" along, as opposed to just smearing the wall. But this is primer so it doesn't really matter. Use a new roller and I can't see how it wouldn't roll.

Comment: Thanks anyway. The simple fact that this concept does not seem to exist in other regions indicate that there's no real need for it, especially given the price difference. I guess I'll buy a bucket of each and see for myself.